# Issues creating a Unit Test stub for this function return using Sinon and Should

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, sinon, should.js

I have the following `health.js` file..

```
exports.endpoint = function (req, res) {
    let http_status = 200;
    res.sendStatus(http_status);
};
```

Where I'm trying to figure out how I can create a Unit Test from this endpoint.

Below is my attempt so far..

```
import { sinon, should } from "../../test-harness";

let health = require('../../../src/endpoints/health');
health.endpoint = sinon.stub();

describe('The health endpoint', function () {
    it('should call .endpoint()', () => {
        health.endpoint.should.have.been.called;
    });
});
```

But it seems to be passing regardless of if I add a `.not` to my `should.have.been.called` statement.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: it('should call .endpoint()', () => {
  health.endpoint()
  health.endpoint.should.have.been.called;
});

Comment: but this test makes no sense